# Why plasma is called state but not phase?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Plasma is considered 4th state of matter but it is not considered a phase.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is sometimes  called a phase https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/state.html

Comment: -1? It's a highly active question:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83658/is-there-a-phase-transition-between-a-gas-and-plasma

Comment: [Here is a link that may answer your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79426/is-a-plasma-a-distinct-phase-of-matter#:~:text=When%20gas%20becomes%20plasma%2C%20it,be%20described%20as%20phase%20transition.)